# Ability to exclude one page from https redirection in nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an app in Kubernetes which is served over https. So now I would like to exclude one URL from that rule and use HTTP to serve it for performance reasons. I am struggling with that the whole day and it seems impossible.

These are my ingress YAML:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: '[{"addresses":["172.31.1.11"],"port":443,"protocol":"HTTPS","serviceName":"myservice:myservice","ingressName":"myservice:myservice","hostname":"app.server.test.mycompany.com","path":"/","allNodes":true}]'
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  creationTimestamp: "2020-02-17T13:14:19Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app-kubernetes-io/instance: mycompany
    app-kubernetes-io/managed-by: Tiller
    app-kubernetes-io/name: mycompany
    helm.sh/chart: mycompany-1.0.0
    io.cattle.field/appId: mycompany
  name: mycompany
  namespace: mycompany
  resourceVersion: "565608"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/mycompany/ingresses/mycompany
  uid: c6b93108-a28f-4de6-a62b-487708b3f5d1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app.server.test.mycompany.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: mycompany
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - app.server.test.mycompany.com
    secretName: mycompany-tls-secret
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 172.31.1.11
```

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: '[{"addresses":["172.31.1.1"],"port":80,"protocol":"HTTP","serviceName":"mycompany:mycompany","ingressName":"mycompany:mycompany-particular-service","hostname":"app.server.test.mycompany.com","path":"/account_name/particular_service/","allNodes":true}]'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-02-17T13:14:19Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app-kubernetes-io/instance: mycompany
    app-kubernetes-io/managed-by: Tiller
    app-kubernetes-io/name: mycompany
    helm.sh/chart: mycompany-1.0.0
    io.cattle.field/appId: mycompany
  name: mycompany-particular-service
  namespace: mycompany
  resourceVersion: "565609"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/mycompany/ingresses/mycompany-particular-service
  uid: 88127a02-e0d1-4b2f-b226-5e8d160c1654
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app.server.test.mycompany.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: mycompany
          servicePort: 80
        path: /account_name/particular_service/
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 172.31.1.11
```

So as you can see from above I would like to server `/particular_service/` over HTTP. Ingress, however, redirects to HTTPS as TLS is enabled for that host in the first ingress.

Is there any way to disable TLS just for that one specific path when the same host is being used for configuration?

In short summary I would like to have:

```
https://app.server.test.mycompany.com
but
http://app.server.test.mycompany.com/account_name/particular_service/
```

Comment: Will you be using this http service externally?

Comment: Yes it has to be accessed from the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested with 2 ingress of the same domain, the first one with tls enabled and the second without tls and it worked.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: echo-https
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myapp.mydomain.com
    secretName: https-myapp.mydomain.com
  rules:
  - host: myapp.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: echo-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  name: echo-http
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: echo-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /insecure
```

By the Nginx [docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#server-side-https-enforcement-through-redirect):

> By default the controller redirects HTTP clients to the HTTPS port 443 using a 308 Permanent Redirect response if TLS is enabled for that Ingress.
>
> This can be disabled globally using `ssl-redirect: "false"` in the NGINX config map, or per-Ingress with the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"` annotation in the particular resource.

Please let me if that helps.

Comment: Hmm, I think I have tried that, but maybe did something wrong. Will try again. Thx.

Comment: It seems to work. I had many overlapping ingress rules, that is why I was not able to use above in the first place. Thx!

Comment: Yes, done. One more thing. Is it possible to do rewrite from https to https for that particular url? With the above configuration I have access to that insecure page over http and https. Which means that when accessing it from https the I am not being redirected to http.

Comment: Yes, the url is access over https because the [path-priority](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/ingress-path-matching.md#path-priority) matches when you use https first. The best solution is create a new ingress with a different domain.

Answer (score 1):

Also add `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect ": "false"`. It had worked for me previously. You can give it a try.